# Is there a way to display an image and draw on top of it using PyQt5, but just get the brush strokes as an image(mouse movements)?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

I want the image as the background, on top of which I can draw. So far, I am able to save the edited image as a whole. I want only the brush strokes / mouse movements to be saved as an image. My code so far is

```
import sys
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Drawer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, img, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StaticContents)
        self.myPenWidth = 10
        self.myPenColor = Qt.white
        self.image = QPixmap("heatmap.png")
        self.path = QPainterPath()
        self.clearImage()

    def clearImage(self):
        self.path = QPainterPath()
        self.image = QPixmap("heatmap.png")
        self.update()

    def saveImage(self, fileName, fileFormat):
        self.image.save(fileName, fileFormat)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.image)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = True
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton and self.drawing:
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.white, 10, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = False

    def sizeHint(self):
        w = self.image.width()
        h = self.image.height()


        return QSize(w, h)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    img_path = 'heatmap.png'
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    btnSave = QPushButton("Save image")
    btnClear = QPushButton("Clear")
    drawer = Drawer(img)

    w.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
    w.layout().addWidget(btnSave)
    w.layout().addWidget(btnClear)
    w.layout().addWidget(drawer)

    btnSave.clicked.connect(lambda: drawer.saveImage("image.jpg", "jpg"))
    btnClear.clicked.connect(drawer.clearImage)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The paintEvent method adds the brush strokes on top of the original image (heatmap.png) here, and I get the brush strokes added on top of the image.

Comment: Use a new blank pixmap with the same size of the original (just remember to `fill(Qt.transparent)` it) and draw on that instead, then paint both of them.

Comment: Hey, sorry but I have never used PyQt5 before, and I am having trouble implementing your suggestion. Where do I add this in my code above? Thanks in advance

Comment: I will consider to add an appropriate answer to your question, but, in the meantime, I strongly suggest you to do some proper research about Qt painting (starting with QPainter and all related classes). If you want to deal with image editing and custom painting, proper knowledge and experience about these topics is expected, you cannot just take some random code and expect it to do what you want. Start to learn the basics of painting using primitive forms (rectangles, lines, ellipses, etc.) and understanding the concepts behind drawing surfaces (QPixmap, QWidget, etc.).

Comment: Hello, I have got it working. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Consider that if you did it following the concepts of your code above you may eventually get some inconsistency caused by the fact that the image is drawn by adapting it to the widget size (scaling its contents), while the mouse drawing is always achieved in widget coordinates. If the widget is resized (for instance, by maximizing the window), the *visible* drawing will not be consistent with the actual image proportions. A possibility would be to use a QTransform to get absolute mouse positions (in a 0-1 range) and apply the reverse both when drawing and when saving.